# How to use `elemIndex` from Data.List on Strings in PureScript?

Tags: string, list, purescript

The problem I am trying to solve looks like this, take an address string:

```
"Street, City, State"
```

and split it into `["Street", "City", "State"]`, in order to do this I am trying to use `elemIndex` like:

```
elemIndex "," "a, b, c"
```

but I realize that this violates the type signature of

```
elemIndex :: String -> List String -> Maybe Int
```

and tried a variation with characters because `[Char]` and `String` are the same type.

```
elemIndex ',' "a, b, c"
```

but that results in a type error as well. Which function is appropriate to do this if `elemIndex` is not appropriate to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `split` function. The type definition is as follows:

```
split :: Pattern -> String -> Array String
```

You should use it as follows:

```
split (Pattern ", ") "Street, City, State"
```

You can view its documentation here: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-strings/3.3.0/docs/Data.String#v:split